# Is it possible to disable loading images (jpg and png only) on Selenium and Chrome webdrive?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In my efforts to improve performance of my selenium testing application I was wondering if it is possible to avoid loading certain files such as images (jpg and png). The parameter "--disable-images" disable all images, including "gif", which in my canse can be a google analytics tag, and I must capture that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it by specifying `profile.managed_default_content_settings.image` in `ChromeOptions`. Example:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

As for only for specific image formats, I don't think it's possible