# Avoid load images and other resources like css when use Selenium in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

Good morning.
I am developing a spider to review a few web pages. I can't do it without using Selenium. But the problem with Selenium is that it consumes a lot of resources and is slow. I am looking for the optimization way.
From what I see the main problem is that Selenium loads the entire website, with all its resources. But I just need javascript and html to work for me. But I don't need images. Can I somehow prevent images from loading in the Selenium browser in C #?

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

    using (IWebDriver driver = SeleniumUtility.GetChromeDriverHidden())
    {
        driver.Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
        string html = driver.PageSource;
    }

    internal static ChromeDriver GetChromeDriverHidden(bool hidden = true)
    {
        ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(".");
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true; // Hide output commands in console

        var options = new ChromeOptions()
        {
            AcceptInsecureCertificates = true // This lets the browser accept the insecure certificate. Set hidden = false
        };

        if (hidden)
        {
            options.AddArgument("headless"); // hide window if added to options
        }

        return new ChromeDriver(service, options);
    }
```

I see [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757073/is-it-possible-to-disable-loading-images-jpg-and-png-only-on-selenium-and-chro), but in C# I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I hope it helps

---

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("headless","--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");
```

---

---

Or

```
    IWebDriver driver;
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.images", 2);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

---

See the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657976/disable-images-in-selenium-google-chromedriver)

Comment: The first option works as of today. The second doesn't.